Why don't scrollview work in div when body scrollview is disabled?
I have this code that pulls text from text file and displays it in pre-code block, the problem is that I'm only able to scroll the entire page (with body overflow enabled) but I can't scroll div itself, even if I force display of scrollbar it stays unactive. What is my mistake here?
<body style="overflow:hidden">
    <div style="margin: 0;padding: 0; height:100%; width: 100%; border: none; overflow: auto;">
    <pre style="margin: 0;padding: 0;  border: none; overflow: auto;">
    <code> <?php echo $content?> </code>
    </pre>
    </div>
</body>

I've tried changing width/height to all available values, and overflow settings too.

You need to give the div or pre a specific "height" so that it can be scrolled
like:
<div style="margin: 0;padding: 0; height:100%; width: 100%; border: none; overflow: auto;">
    <pre style="margin: 0;padding: 0; height:150px; border: none; overflow: auto;">
        <code> <?php echo $content?> </code>
    </pre>
</div>


Thanks, that works. But as i understand it wont work if height is % of the screen? it needs to be specifically some pixels amount?

I've tested with vh and it now worked, i guess i had a problem in something other before, because i've tried doing this a few times. Tanks for response

Height as a % is a percentage of the container.   Since you don't specify a height for the body tag, it will grow as needed, and the div will be 100% of the body's height.   If you specify height: 100vh for 100 view height for either the div or the body it should work.  For the body it will limit the body size to the view height and the 100% of the div will equal that.   For the div it will limit the height and the body won't grow.

You need a height that's different from your current 100%. For example height: 100vh. This will make sure that the size of the container equals to the size of the view-port in height and then you will have a scroll for it.


.my-code {
    height: 100vh;
}
<body style="overflow:hidden">
    <div class="my-code" style="margin: 0;padding: 0; width: 100%; border: none; overflow: auto;">
    <pre style="margin: 0;padding: 0;  border: none; overflow: auto;">
    <code>

function solveNQueen(n) {
    let result = [];
    dfs(new Array(n), 0, result);
    return result;
}

function dfs(queens, row, result) {
    let n = queens.length;
    
    if (row === n) {
        result.push(buildResult(queens));
        return;
    }
    
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (isValid(queens, row, i)) {
            queens[row] = i;
            dfs(queens, row + 1, result);
            queens[row] = null;
        }
    }
}

function isValid(queens, row, col) {
    for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        if (queens[i] === col || queens[i] - i === col - row || queens[i] + i === col + row) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function buildResult(queens) {
    let result = [];
    let n = queens.length;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        let str = '';
        for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (queens[i] === j) {
                str += 'Q ';
            } else {
                str += '. ';
            }
        }
        result.push(str);
    }
    return result;
}    
    </code>
    </pre>
    </div>
</body>



